# Help understanding a volume problem in xyz

Tags: multivariable-calculus, volume

$z=y^2$, $x+2y=4$,  $x=0$, $y=0$, $z=0$. How do I find the volume？ I tried graphing it, since it's restricted to the first quadrant. How exactly would I determine the volume? I'm not sure what $f(x,y)$ is, also the limits are kind of fuzzy to me.

Comment: For the limits, $x$ goes from $0$ to $4$, $y$ goes from $0$ to $2 - \frac12 x$, $z$ goes from $0$ to $y^2$.

Comment: what is the function f(x,y)? Shouldn't there be something that fits inside a triple integral?

Comment: You didn't actually say what the question was. But I'm assuming you're finding the volume bounded by the graphs of $z = y^2$, $x + 2y = 4$, $x = 0$, $y = 0$, and $z = 0$. In which case the function $f(x,y,z)$ is just $1$.

Comment: I remember seeing that in class, can you explain what that means? When the entire function is 1? I didn't catch why when the prof. said so.

Comment: also, how is x from 0-4 when others have variables in their limits? Are your limits arbitrary?

Comment: I would say, $V=\int_{0}^{2} \int_{0}^{(4-2y)}\int_{0}^{y^2}\,dz\,dx\,dy \quad \left(or\,  V = \int_{0}^{2} (4-2y)y^2\,dy\right) \quad =\cdots=\frac{8}{3}$

Comment: can you explain the limits? They don't seem to make sense considering the derivatives don't match the variable in the integrand.